# Existing record (spl_id) now showing not found

Tags: api, openfda

We are storing **spl_id** in our DB and using it as primary key in the API. But after some time, when we search it via the API, we get the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "No matches found!"
  }
}
```

Here is an example:

- In this use case, we used the following **spl_id**: a732f55b-9001-34b8-e053-2a95a90a23ab
- URL used for searching medicine:
  https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?api_key=xxxxxx&search=spl_id:a732f55b-9001-34b8-e053-2a95a90a23ab

On the other end:

- Here is a current valid API example: https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=spl_id:999ea441-65f0-9946-e053-2a95a90a0753

Not sure why that id is no longer available, but it was valid when it was first pulled from the external API into our local DB.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure  if it is a mistake or on purpose but you shouldn't post your api key in online

Comment: @SuperKogito Yea..that was one of our dev keys. But I have updated anyways. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I have provided the answer on GitHub: https://github.com/FDA/open.fda.gov/issues/196#issuecomment-728228050